# Enumerate bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, enumerate

I would like to map `\supercite{entry}` to an enumerated list in the references. I made a first step via

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\enumerate}{\endenumerate}{\item}
```

which returns `1) ___, 2) ___, etc.`

But I would prefer the number with a dot (so `1. ___, 2. ___, etc.`).

Can someone help me there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add `\usepackage{enumitem}` to your preamble, then use `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]}{\end{enumerate}}{\item}`.

Comment: Wonderful idea. Can you post your comment as answer so that I can upvote and mark it as solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functionality of [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to update the `label` display for your bibliography enumeration. Add

```
\usepacakge{enumitem}
```

to your preamble and then define the new bibliography environment like this:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]}% bibliography environment start
  {\end{enumerate}}% bibliography environment end
  {\item}% per-item
```